# adb error in android studio

Tags: android, sdk, adb, platform-tools

I've tried every proposed solution on the internet and nothing is working. Android studio was working fine then one day out of nowhere it kept giving me this error on every project

`unable to locate adb`

I tried navigating to my adb.exe and kill-sever and restart it but the adb.exe directory is not in my platform-tools folder under sdk.

I've tried uninstalling android studio and reinstalling it. A post suggested that it could be my AVG security but that was not the issue.  I've tried updating the platform-tools and it freezes here

[image]

Comment: Please check if your directory exists or your directory permission is allowed to write

Comment: If which directory exists?

Comment: The directory where you download & install the Android components

Comment: ok how to i check the permissions in cmd?

Comment: Simply insert command in cmd for checking user permission of directory, depends on Mac or other platforms, Google can help you

Comment: I had permissions it seems the problem was the system path variable was missing. Once I added it back I was able to update the sdk platform-tools which solved the issue. Thanks for your help

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score -1):

```
Close android studio.
open a command window. 
type adb devices
no devices? 
trouble shoot connection and drivers and device developer option
see a device?
   type adb shell
   type ls -l
   type su
su not found? download or activate your superuser app
no problems with any step?
 open android studio and try again with it's terminal emulator
```

Comment: every time i type adb in cmd it says adb not recognized.

Comment: check for C:\Users\ *USERNAME* \AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools

Comment: your computer System Variables needs:

Comment: ANDROID_HOME  C:\Users\ *name* \AppData\Local|Android\sdk

Comment: yes i have C:\Users\ USERNAME \AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools

Comment: I added the system variable and instead of going to the end of the download and stopping it didn't load anything

Comment: Adding the path variable did end up working. There were three sdk folders because I tried to uninstall it twice but once I deleted the 2 oldest folders I was successfully able to update my sdk platform-tools which solved my issue. Thanks!